# horizontally centering columns inside .row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having struggle to horizontally center columns inside .row in bootstrap 3. I tried many methods, from margin:0 auto; to display:flex; etc etc. and it just won't "move" in to the middle. I'm posting jsfiddle too so you can see it in real time :

https://jsfiddle.net/z2Lo4txL/4/

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row center-col">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pattern">
            <h3>Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="f-icon">
                    <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline x5"></i>
                </div>
                        <div class="f-body">
                            <p class="pt5">Curabitur rhoncus dolor sem, vel   interdum quam congue in. In sed est faucibus quol. Feugiat iunnonies massa consisa der.</p>
                        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pattern">
            <h3>Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="f-icon">
                    <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline x5"></i>
                </div>
                        <div class="f-body">
                            <p class="pt5">Curabitur rhoncus dolor sem, vel interdum quam congue in. In sed est faucibus quol. Feugiat iunnonies massa consisa der.</p>
                        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pattern">
            <h3>Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="f-icon">
                    <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline x5"></i>
                </div>
                        <div class="f-body">
                            <p class="pt5">Curabitur rhoncus dolor sem, vel interdum quam congue in. In sed est faucibus quol. Feugiat iunnonies massa consisa der.</p>
                        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pattern">
            <h3>Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="f-icon">
                    <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline x5"></i>
                </div>
                        <div class="f-body">
                            <p class="pt5">Curabitur rhoncus dolor sem, vel interdum quam congue in. In sed est faucibus quol. Feugiat iunnonies massa consisa der.</p>
                        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pattern">
            <h3>Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="f-icon">
                    <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline x5"></i>
                </div>
                        <div class="f-body">
                            <p class="pt5">Curabitur rhoncus dolor sem, vel interdum quam congue in. In sed est faucibus quol. Feugiat iunnonies massa consisa der.</p>
                        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pattern">
            <h3>Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="f-icon">
                    <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline x5"></i>
                </div>
                        <div class="f-body">
                            <p class="pt5">Curabitur rhoncus dolor sem, vel interdum quam congue in. In sed est faucibus quol. Feugiat iunnonies massa consisa der.</p>
                        </div>    
        </div>                                                            
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center-col {
margin:0 auto;
}

.pattern {
background-image:url(http://i1cevic.com/img/pattern.jpg);
margin:5px;
}

.f-icon {
float:left;
}

.x5 { font-size:40px!important }

h3 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing:normal;
font-size: 18px;
color:#303233;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: At the very least, it's because you aren't targeting your column but the row.

    `.center-col .pattern{
        margin:0 auto;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on [Column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering), use `col-push-*` like this:

```
<div class="col-md-push-4 col-md-4 col-sm-push-3 col-sm-6 pattern">Content here</div>
```

I just updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/z2Lo4txL/7/

Or you can make any your content inside a div with `row` class, then use `col-*-offset-*` or `col-*-push*` to make it center like:

```
<div class="row>
   <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6></div>
</div>
```

If you want it display on `sm-6` you have `sm-6` to make this enough `col-12`, let divide it for 2 spaces (left and right), we have result is `offset-3` or `push-3`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your .pattern to

```
.pattern {
    background-image: url(http://i1cevic.com/img/pattern.jpg);
    margin: 5px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/z2Lo4txL/6/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS3 **Flexbox** Layout Mode:

```css
    .center-col {
      display: flex;            // <-- to enable Flexbox
      flex-direction: column;   // <-- changes flex direction
      align-items: center;      // <-- centers perpendicularly to flex direction
    }
```

learn more:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
http://flexboxin5.com/
http://flexboxfroggy.com/